# Open a visualforce page from a managed package page: URL No Longer Exists

Tags: visualforce, javascript, managed-package, url

I am trying to open a normal visualforce page (that is NOT a part of the managed package) from a visualforce page that is IN managed package.

This button I have on the visualforce page in manage package:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Open" onclick="window.open('apex/MyPage'); return false;" />
```

The `MyPage` is NOT in the managed package.

By clicking on the button a new popup window appears, so javascript works well. 
But the problem is that I am getting the following error message and no content of the `MyPage`:

> URL No Longer Exists 
>  You have attempted to reach a URL that no longer
>   exists on salesforce.com.

After some research I've found a difference between URL of the both pages.

Managed package visualforce page with that command button:

```
https://customDomainName--PREFIX.csXX.visual.force.com/apex/PageInManagedPackage
```

Another page that should be opened (`MyPage`, not in managed package) is opened with the same prefix in URL. But if I replace the PREFIX with a `c` then the page will load without problems:

```
https://customDomainName--c.csXX.visual.force.com/apex/MyPage          <- this works
https://customDomainName--PREFIX.csXX.visual.force.com/apex/MyPage     <- this not
```

How you can see the only difference is that external page opened with a prefix in URL could not be shown :(

My question is, what is wrong with my button? Why an "external" page opens with a wrong URL? Is it a managed package "feature"? How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issues:

1. URL No Longer Exists

   - Error is happening because your path to the page is incorrect and is missing the leading `/` which creates a URL which is relative to the current page rather than relative to the host.
2. Path to the page outside of the managed package namespace

   - The default VF namespace is `c__` and you can specify this in your page path. This allows you to avoid hardcoding a fully qualified URI.

`<apex:commandButton value="Open" onclick="window.open('/apex/c__MyPage'); return false;" />`

Related: [How to redirect to default namespace vf page from managed package vf page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22132/)

Comment: ooh, didn't know about the `__c` prefix, nice

Comment: WOW! Great hint Mark, didn't know about `c__PageName`, but this is so obvious! :) Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think pages opened from within a managed package must always be fully qualified with the full URL, so your button would have to be:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Open" onclick="window.open('https://c.csXX.visual.force.com/apex/MyPage'); return false;" />
```

Obviously, this will give you some challenges to get the correct pod in your URL, but other than that should work.

I believe it is indeed a feature of managed packages.

Comment: I've just tried to hard code the whole correct URL (w/o prefix) to the button and a popup page opens correctly. So the challenge is to generate this URL without prefix dynamically :) Thanks.

Comment: Would a custom setting be dynamic enough perhaps?

Comment: I dont think so. It is not always the same.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that this will solve your problem but try this one :

```
< apex:commandButton value="Open" onclick="window.open('{!$Page.MyPage}'); return false;" />
```