# Name Mismatch Certificate error when window.open()'ing to visual.force.com page from visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, ssl, certificates

I have a visualforce page with an iframe'd app.  When you click a link in the iframe, it communicates with the parent window via postMessage and instructs the JS running on the parent window (visualforce page) to perform a window.open(url, '_blank').

The parent page hostname is like: https://foobar.na6.visual.force.com

The window.open hostname is like: https://snafu.foobar.na6.visual.force.com

I'm then getting a "Privacy Error" in chrome.  It says:

> [!] Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from
> snafu.foobar.na6.visual.force.com (for example, passwords, messages,
> or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
>
> This server could not prove that it is
> snafu.foobar.na6.visual.force.com; its security certificate is from
> *.na6.force.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

In chrome, this error happens every time we click the link, and we have to manually choose to proceed to the site.

Is there something we can do on our end to make this issue go away, or is this something SFDC needs to resolve?

Comment: Are you manually constructing the url for the `window.open()` call? Where does the prepended `snafu.` come from? (root question: do you actually need it there?)

Comment: Yeah, i'm manually constructing it.  "snafu" is needed, yeah.  the url wont work correctly without it.

Comment: hmm, it doesn't look like foobar is needed though... when i remove the foobar part it works without a certificate problem.

Comment: Is the name that you are prepending part of a managed package namespace? How do you know what is prepended? If you make the `window.open()` URL relative instead of absolute, does the SFDC webserver redirect you to the "proper" host name without a cert warning?

Comment: I believe that it is, yeah.  I see that both "snafu" and "foobar" are labeled as Namespaces in Custom Settings and have their own Custom Settings that can be Manage'd.  I don't think making the URL relative will work because that will only change the path, not the hostname.  And I tried the link path under "foobar" and it didn't work.  It only works under "snafu",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a relative URL in the `window.open()` method if you specify the namespace of the managed package page in the path. Salesforce will automagically redirect you to the appropriate hostname when it resolves the namespace and loads the page.

If the managed package's namespace is `snafu`, the path to the VF page including this namespace would be `/apex/snafu__TheManagedVFPage`.

For reference, the default namespace that prefixes all pages that are not part of a package is `c__`. The path to your VF page can be written as `/apex/c__YourPageName`.

A related question with some additional details: [How to redirect to default namespace vf page from managed package vf page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/22132/)