# Managed package Visualforce page URL on subscribed organization?

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, isv

When I develop a package and use a Visualforce page with additional parameters as custom button, URL button link doesn't work in subscriber org.

For example, my page has name MyBeautifulPage and URL button link `/apex/MyBeautifulPage?param=Value` works great in Developer Edition org where package is developed, however, in subscriber org that button doesn't work.

Looks like it is need to determine the current URL and instance name to transform the URL correctly from  `eu6.force.com` to `package-name.eu6.visual.force.com`, from  `archie--devarchie.cs13.my.salesforce.com` to `archie--devarchie--package-name.cs13.visual.force.com`, from  `production.my.force.com` to `production--package-name.eu10.visual.force.com`.

Looks like I can get `InstanceName` from `Organization` by querying [select InstanceName from Organization], probably I could get current URL by `System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()`, however it is not clear how to process it altogether correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a hack to make this simplier.

It is enough to prefix page name with package name like following:

`/apex/package-name__MyBeautifulPage?param=Value`

and Salesforce will redirect to the correct link.

Comment: You can also use as package-name "c" in case of unprefixed environment. In my case of dev setup of dev/test org. Similar topic is here -- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22132/how-to-redirect-to-default-namespace-vf-page-from-managed-package-vf-page?noredirect=1&lq=1